# How Group By Queries in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, wikipedia

I am working on a project where I would like to query the wikipedia database so I could bring some results ... I am using a Javascript application and Jquery with a self suggestion field as the user types a list of words should appear ....

For this to happen I need to create a query in elasticsearch by bringing all categories and only them into the results.

Type a SQL = SELECT Field FROM Table Group By Field ..

How would I do this?

My Test is basic and return all objects....

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["category"], 
      "query":  "*"
    }
  }
}
```

Part of result is:

```
{
  "took": 34,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 13,
    "successful": 13,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2117924,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "ptwikionary_content",
        "_type": "page",
        "_id": "41115",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "redirect": [],
          "template": [
            "Predefinição:-pt-",
            "Predefinição:cabeçalho-idioma",
            "Predefinição:nome categoria",
            "Predefinição:pt",
            "Predefinição:nome língua",
            "Predefinição:flex.pt",
            "Predefinição:link preto",
            "Predefinição:paroxítona",
            "Predefinição:gramática",
            "Predefinição:gramática/core",
            "Predefinição:etimologia",
            "Predefinição:escopo",
            "MediaWiki:Log"
          ],
          "content_model": "wikitext",
          "heading": [
            "Português",
            "Adjetivo",
            "Antônimo",
            "Etimologia"
          ],
          "source_text": """
={{-pt-}}=
==Adjetivo==
{{flex.pt|s=desumilde|p=desumildes}}
{{paroxítona|de|su|mil|de}}, {{gramática|c2g}}
# que não é [[humilde]]

===Antônimo===
* [[humilde]]

=={{etimologia|pt}}==
: {{escopo|Morfologia}} [[des-]] + [[humilde]].

[[Categoria:Adjetivo (Português)]]
""",
          "version_type": "external",
          "wiki": "ptwiktionary",
          "auxiliary_text": [
            "  Singular Plural Masculino desumilde desumildes Feminino"
          ],
          "language": "pt",
          "title": "desumilde",
          "version": 2491983,
          "external_link": [],
          "namespace_text": "",
          "namespace": 0,
          "text_bytes": 274,
          "incoming_links": 2,
          "text": "de.su.mil.de, comum aos dois géneros que não é humilde  humilde  (Morfologia) des- + humilde.",
          "category": [
            "!Entrada (Português)",
            "Polissílabo (Português)",
            "Paroxítona (Português)",
            "Entrada com etimologia (Português)",
            "Adjetivo (Português)"
          ],
          "defaultsort": false,
          "outgoing_link": [
            "desumilde",
            "desumildes",
            "des-",
            "feminino",
            "humilde",
            "masculino",
            "plural",
            "português",
            "singular",
            "Categoria:Português"
          ],
          "timestamp": "2018-03-29T21:53:29Z",
          "popularity_score": 0.000065252908710355
        }
      },
      {
```

How i Get category list from elasticsearch??? Type Sql :

Comment: It's called terms aggregation in ES, see here for doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Answer (score 5):

Use [aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) for this. Here's an example:

```
GET _search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "categories" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "category" }
        }
    }
}
```